# Upload a file to azure blob storage through JMeter using Azure SDK for Java

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

How can I upload a file to Azure Blob Storage through JMeter using JAVA programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet you can use as a basis:

```
DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient =
   fileSystemClient.getDirectoryClient("my-directory");

DataLakeFileClient fileClient = directoryClient.createFile("uploaded-file.txt");

File file = new File("C:\\Users\\constoso\\mytestfile.txt");

//   InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(file);
InputStream targetStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

long fileSize = file.length();

fileClient.append(targetStream, 0, fileSize);

fileClient.flush(fileSize);
```

You can put it in a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and use [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) as the language

More information:

- [Quickstart: Azure Blob Storage client library for Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell%2Cmanaged-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli)
- [Use Java to manage directories and files in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-java#upload-a-file-to-a-directory)